# HTML CSS Border help

Tags: html, css

i am trying to get the bottom border one color but because in the table border is set to 0
but when i set it to one it shows.

i put the following code in the < TD>

```
 style="border-bottom:thin; border-bottom-color:#006; "
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the borders of table cells or the entire table?

Comment: a table cells i am trying to modify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
border-bottom:thin;
border-bottom-color:#006
```

is the same as

```
border-bottom: thin none ???; /* Where ??? is whatever the color property is set to */
border-bottom-color:#006
```

(because properties you don't specify are [set to the initial values](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#propdef-border-bottom))

which is the same as

```
border-bottom-width: thin;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-color: ???;  /* Where ??? is whatever the color property is set to */
border-bottom-color: #006;
```

If you use short cut property names, be careful about what you are resetting.

Use this instead:

```
border-bottom: thin solid #006;
```

Comment: @David, I read the question a few more times and decided your interpretation is probably more correct, so I deleted my post.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're not providing all that much information to go on, but here is something to look for:

Does the table have the style border-collapse: collapse?  (this collapses the td borders so that there is not a border for the left of one td and the right of the next one - they use the same border when they're next to each other).